# Why is the intersection of rays needed in optics?

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

In optics,to locate the position of a object we need two or more rays starting from the object. The intersection of the rays gives the position of the image.

So, why is the intersection of rays important or needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images look like objects because rays of light come from the image in the same way as they come from the object.

In a ray diagram the intersection of reflected or refracted rays shows the location of a point where rays diverge in the same way as they diverge from the original object.  As a result this point looks like the object.  It is the location of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Intersection of rays is nothing but intersection of light rays which carry the information of image!

Now coming to your question:

A single ray can't represent all the information about the image therefore it is due to a number of light rays that bounce back from every position of the object that you are able to see it's image at the point of intersection because that is the point where every information about the image can be seen.

Answer (score 0):

After reaching the point of crossing the rays part on different directions, as if the real object were there.